# Network request failed React native

Tags: ios, networking, react-native

I've used this code to make a call to url and I got Network request failed
But if I replace the IP address with specified domain (like abc.com/types). Anyone know why and how to fix it?

```
 fetch("192.168.1.99/SP/public/api/types")
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseJSON) => {
                console.log(responseJSON);
                if (responseJSON.code == 200) {
                    console.log("OK: " + responseJSON.result);
                } else {
                    console.log("FAIL: " + responseJSON.message);
                }
            }).catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
```

Ps: I've setup AppTransportSecuritySetting already.

Comment: Add http:// resolve problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing Protocol http://

```
fetch("http://192.168.1.99/SP/public/api/types")
                .then((response) => response.json())
                .then((responseJSON) => {
                    console.log(responseJSON);
                    if (responseJSON.code == 200) {
                        console.log("OK: " + responseJSON.result);
                    } else {
                        console.log("FAIL: " + responseJSON.message);
                    }
                }).catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
```